# Crashlytics Crash report around Maps SDK, gmscore::renderer::GLState::Flush()

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

Our app has quite a lot of crashes happening to users, reported by crashlytics, however we are unable to reproduce it on our end. Here is the full crash report:

```
    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  TheBarCode                     0x100ccc2d8 gmscore::renderer::GLState::Flush() + 16388
1  TheBarCode                     0x100cd7630 gmscore::renderer::GLScopedContext::~GLScopedContext() + 31600
2  TheBarCode                     0x100d3a314 -[GMSEntityRendererView setFrame:] + 436308
3  TheBarCode                     0x100d82578 -[GMSVectorMapView setFrame:] + 184912
4  UIKitCore                      0x18f6af878 -[UIView(Geometry) _applyAutoresizingMaskWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 576
5  UIKitCore                      0x18f6b0510 -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 236
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18b18195c __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
7  CoreFoundation                 0x18b084fb0 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 416
8  UIKitCore                      0x18f6af5e4 -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 156
9  UIKitCore                      0x18f6b082c -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 688
10 UIKitCore                      0x18f6b00e0 -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValuesToBoundsOnly:] + 528
11 UIKitCore                      0x18f6b04ac -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 136
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18b18195c __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18b084fb0 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 416
14 UIKitCore                      0x18f6af5e4 -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 156
15 UIKitCore                      0x18f5f76fc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 148
16 UIKitCore                      0x18f6b7090 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 1032
17 Gradientable                   0x101738798 UIView.swizzled_layoutSubviews() + 50 (Gradientable.swift:50)
18 Gradientable                   0x1017388d0 @objc UIView.swizzled_layoutSubviews() + 4359784656 (<compiler-generated>:4359784656)
19 UIKitCore                      0x18f6ca17c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140
20 QuartzCore                     0x191c322c0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
21 QuartzCore                     0x191c3843c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480
22 QuartzCore                     0x191c43140 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136
23 QuartzCore                     0x191b8b884 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 304
24 QuartzCore                     0x191bb5574 CA::Transaction::commit() + 676
25 QuartzCore                     0x191bb5f68 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
26 CoreFoundation                 0x18b12be68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
27 CoreFoundation                 0x18b126d54 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
28 CoreFoundation                 0x18b127320 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
29 CoreFoundation                 0x18b126adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
30 GraphicsServices               0x1950c7328 GSEventRunModal + 104
31 UIKitCore                      0x18f23463c UIApplicationMain + 1936
32 TheBarCode                     0x10082756c main + 21 (Preference.swift:21)
33 libdyld.dylib                  0x18afb0360 start + 4
```

The other strange thing is that we are not receiving any additional added (on which screen does it happen) logs along with the crash.

## Additional Information:

Recently we have upgraded our application for iOS 13 and xcode 11. By doing so, we have also updated google maps iOS SDK to 3.8.0. After upgrading we are receiving crash reports.  On the previously used version we never experienced this crash i.e. 2.7.0

In our application we have multiple instances of `GMSMapView` i.e. around 8 instances embedded in a `UIPageViewController`. For the sake of memory management we only keep the visible version of `GMSMapView` and discard other instances in `viewDidDisappear` method of view controller. Here is the code that we are using to setup map and clearing map.

```
func setupMapView() {

    let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = false
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .notDetermined {
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = false
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        self.myLocationButtonContainer.isHidden = false
    } else {
        self.myLocationButtonContainer.isHidden = true
    }

    self.mapContainer.insertSubview(mapView, at: 0)

    mapView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()

    let iconGenerator = GMUCustomClusterIconGenerator()
    let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
    let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
    renderer.delegate = self

    self.clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
    self.clusterManager?.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)

    self.mapView = mapView

    self.setUpMarkers()

    self.restoreMapCameraPosition(animated: false)
}

func clearMapView() {

    self.clusterManager?.clearItems()

    self.mapView?.clear()
    self.mapView?.removeFromSuperview()

    self.mapView = nil
    self.clusterManager = nil
}
```

Screenshots from crashlytics:

[image]

Screenshot from the data tab of crashlytics:

[image]

Comment: I'm having practically the same issue. With not much information on what actually happened before the crash. However, all of the crashes are on iOS 12 and lower versions.

Comment: for us the crashes are also occurring on iOS 13 as well :(

Comment: We are having this problem as well (BAD ACCESS on gmscore::renderer::GLState::Flush()). We tried to upgrade our Google Maps SDK version to the latest one but the crashes are still happening. Although, in the latest BETA we published on TestFlight, we noticed that users are reporting crashes to happen while the app is in background.

Comment: I am also having this issue, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, I remove google map view from view hierarchy and memory as soon as it's not visible to users to save memory similar to the questioner. Version where I see this is 3.8.0. I will contact google support with this issue and keep you posted.

Comment: This issue is already reported. You can check it here https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/152145655

Answer (score -1):

Just downgrade to 3.7.0 iOS Maps SDK.

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3.7.0'
```

Comment: Do we know what's actually causing it on 3.8.0?

Comment: This is not a solution. As reported from the release notes change, there is no code change between 3.7.0 and 3.8.0: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases?hl=it

Comment: @DanielePantaleone Surely this is not a solution. As i write in the question that we are unable to reproduce it on our end. Since I downgraded to version '3.7.0' I did not receive the same crash report on crashlytics. I am not sure whats going on :?

Comment: I didn't try version 3.7.0 as we are not using cocoapods to manage dependencies and I haven't yet found the 3.7.0 archive anywhere to try it out.

Comment: I managed to get the 3.7.0 archive and released a BETA version of our app. I can confirm indeed that the crashes are not happening anymore (not seen on Firebase console, nor reported by our users)